# How to avoid duplicates when loading multiple ads using multiple AdLoader objects?

Tags: android, admob, google-dfp

I'm using Google Native Ads to load multiple custom template ads in my app, each with its own ad unit ID.

As it states [here](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/native/start):

> If you need to request multiple ads in parallel, you can always use multiple AdLoader objects.

I use multiple AdLoader objects in parallel in a screen. Until play services ads version 18.0.0, I used a [Correlator](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/Correlator) object to make sure the ads are correlated and to not receive duplicates.

Since the upgrade to  play services ads version 18, this has stopped working and in version 18.1.0 the `Correlator` class is deprecated as seen in the [release notes](https://developers.google.com/ad-manager/mobile-ads-sdk/android/rel-notes)

> Removed the Correlator class and its associated APIs. This feature was previously non-functional.

So my question is: what to use instead of the correlator when loading multiple native ads on the same screen? Documentation says nothing about this, I haven't found anything related to this issue.

Comment: Have you got any duplicated ads? I mean in the release notes it says this feature was non-functional. "Removed the Correlator class and its associated APIs. This feature was previously non-functional". Isn't AdMob already refining based on Ad Unit ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've contacted Google support on this matter. Turns out they will add the Correlator class back in a future SDK update, having multiple requests for this scenario.